# Minimization of error of distances

Tags: regression, optimization

I have a set of input points $(x_i, y_i)$ and a point is drawn at $(p, q)$. This gives me a distance vector $d_i$ of L2 distances. Later, each point $(x_i, y_i)$ moves to a new point $(x_i', y_i')$ and I want to find the new point $(p', q')$ that minimizes the MSE error of the new distances $d'$ to $d$. In other words, find the point $(p', q')$ such that $(d'_i - d_i)^2$ is minimized.

I can do this relatively simply with an optimizer, but I'm wondering if there's a closed form solution for this or if this is a known problem with a solution that I don't know about? This feels very much like a transformation of a linear regression but I am struggling to figure out how.

The application is I am taking input from a camera and with facial landmark detection, can determine a set of landmark points on the face. I want to persist a drawing on the face even as the face moves, sort of like a virtual tattoo.